# Is there any known work planned to cover the missing years of Ahsoka Tano

Tags: star-wars

We see Ahsoka leave the Jedi order in the *Clone Wars* TV series.

Then we see her return in the *Rebels* TV series, 16 years later.

There is a big gap where we don't know what happened to her.

Her story always seemed interesting. Is anything currently known about this period of her life, or is anything known to be in the works to cover this?

Comment: I Asked this question before book was announced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes

[Star Wars: Ahsoka](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aw/d/1484705661/ref=mp_s_a_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1475322328&sr=8-1&pi=SY200_QL40&keywords=star%20wars%20Star%20Wars%3A%20Ahsoka)

From the publisher:

> Star Wars: Ahsoka Book Overview: Fans have long wondered what happened to Ahsoka after she left the Jedi Order near the end of the Clone Wars, and before she re-appeared as the mysterious Rebel operative Fulcrum in the Disney XD TV series, Star Wars Rebels. Finally, her story will begin to be told. Following her experiences with the Jedi and the devastation of Order 66, Ahsoka is unsure she can be part of a larger whole ever again. But her desire to fight the evils of the Empire and protect those who need it will lead her right to Bail Organa, and the Rebel Alliance.